# Why does ActiveRecord provide .delete_all and not .truncate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

It seems strange that I have to manually execute SQL to use the TRUNCATE command. Is there something bad about it that DHH is protecting me against?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `TRUNCATE` on some databases does not run triggers. Using `DELETE` for each row will still run triggers. `TRUNCATE` also cannot be rolled back, so if you did a `.destroy_all` in a transaction, it would erase all the data even if you tried to rollback.

So, yes, you are being protected against the effects of truncate.

Comment: So why don't they have a `truncate` method that raises an error if you try to call it from within a transaction? That would IMO satisfy @seamusabshere but still mitigate the worst of this.  In explaining why it raises an error, the documentation would be forced to explain risks.  Just my $0.02

Comment: I believe `TRUNCATE` is transaction-safe in MySQL and PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using MySQL or Postgre and not SQlite3 (which doesn't support `TRUNCATE`), you could add the following method to your model.

```
def self.truncate
  self.connection_pool.with_connection { |c| c.truncate(table_name) }
end
```

Note that this would not invoke ActiveRecord callbacks.  There are better ways to do this that don't tie your code to a specific DB implementation, but even this is better than writing the SQL yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There are many use cases for `TRUNCATE`, and in my opinion, the answers given here are very insufficient.  Using Postgres as an example:

- `TRUNCATE` is definitely transaction safe in some RDBMS, as already noted by jsears.  It can be rolled back, at least in Postgres.  Isn't Rails supposed to be db-agnostic and allow for such things?
- `TRUNCATE` will also execute `BEFORE TRUNCATE` or `AFTER TRUNCATE` triggers in Postgres.  If you are expecting a `DELETE` trigger to fire on `TRUNCATE` that's your design fault!
- `TRUNCATE` performs far quicker than `DELETE` especially for large datasets because it's a single short DDL statement.
- In Postgres' MVCC architecture, `TRUNCATE` removes all index and table bloat.

For these reasons it's crazy to me that Rails does not support `TRUNCATE`.  No, I don't think the reasons given are good ones.

Answer (score -3):

Take a look at Model.destroy_all and active record : dependent => :destroy relations.  If you don't specify :dependent => :destory, some of the defaults is to set relation to null but not destroy the record.